# Getting results from sql statement in dart, odbc

Tags: html, odbc, dart

i got i hope simple question but i can't find answers in internet or i just still dont understand how to do that.

I want to execute sql statement and than get result and insert in my table, but i can't find proper function for that like there are in jdcb.

i found some examples but still dunno what to do.

code:

```
  static void RegisterTable()
  {
    var hStmt = new SqlHandle();

    sqlAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, MyConnect, hStmt);

    sqlPrepare(hStmt, "SELECT R.[ID],U.[NAME],C.[CAR_NAME],R.[DESTINATION],R.[START_DATE],R.[END_DATE],R.[STATUS] FROM CAR_BOOKING.Registr_car R JOIN CAR_BOOKING.CARS C ON R.Car_id = C.id JOIN CAR_BOOKING.Users_table U ON U.id = R.user_id WHERE R.STATUS !=2;", SQL_NTS);

    // Bind result set columns.
    var id = new SqlIntBuffer();
    var name = new SqlStringBuffer(70);
    var carname = new SqlStringBuffer(70);
    var destination = new SqlStringBuffer(70);
    var startdate = new SqlDateBuffer(70);
    var enddate = new SqlDateBuffer();
    var status = new SqlIntBuffer(70);

    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 1, id.ctype(), id.address(), id.length(),null);
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 2, name.ctype(), name.address(), name.length(),null);
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 3, carname.ctype(), carname.address(), carname.length(),null);
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 4, destination.ctype(), destination.address(), destination.length(),null);
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 5, startdate.ctype(), startdate.address(), startdate.length(),null);
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 6, enddate.ctype(), enddate.address(), enddate.length(),null);
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 6, status.ctype(), status.address(), status.length(),null);

    sqlExecute(hStmt);

    List<Object> result = sqlFetch(hStmt);

    sqlFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);
  }
```

How to get this result to any container like List or print into rows ?

Comment: What database are you using? Did you add any package for database access? Where did you find this example?
There is an ODBC package on http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/odbc . The readme contains a basic example.

Comment: Im using MS sql, and this example is from ur link, but i still dont know how to take these string that the statement result for me,
And yes, i added packaged, but i haven't even compile this, bcoz like i said, i dont know how to get objects or from my statement i executed.

Comment: This package is very new and might evolve to be easier to use. Currently the API looks somewhat low level but not too hard. You have skipped a few steps from the readme, especially **connect** (not sure if the version is mandatory). 
The tests contain a few examples to learn from
https://code.google.com/p/dart-odbc/source/browse/trunk/test/odbc_test.dart and https://code.google.com/p/dart-odbc/source/browse/trunk/test/src/test_fetch.dart

Comment: I somehow now understand how it works, but this time i have errorswith odbc libs.

1.
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://127.0.0.1:8080/packages/t:odbc_ext
An error occurred loading file: package:t:odbc_ext
---------------------------------------------------
2.[web] GET /packages/t:odbc_ext => Could not find asset t:odbc_ext|lib.

Comment: @Zeronader did you succeeded in this, can you help in my request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25750834/how-to-use-odbc-binding-for-dart