# how to use ODBC binding for Dart

Tags: dart, odbc

I wanted to use the ODBC binding for DART [this one](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/odbc) in my app, I'm using ORACLE XE database, but did not get how to set it up, though I read the basic example in the read me :(

Attached a print screen of my ORACLE XE ODB setup, suceed connection, and simple SQL statement,

Appreciate to know the following:
1. Hoe to set-up my ODBC in DART,
2. How to get the same SQL statement executed.

I wrote the below:

```dart
void main() {
  // Allocate an environment handle.
 var hEnv = new SqlHandle();   
 sqlAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, null, hEnv);    
 // Set ODBC version to be used.
 var version = new SqlPointer()..value = SQL_OV_ODBC3;    
 sqlSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, version, 0);    
 // Allocate a connection handle.
 var hConn = new SqlHandle();

sqlAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, hConn);

// Connect.
sqlConnect(hConn, "XE", SQL_NTS, "SYSTEM", SQL_NTS, "myPasswords", SQL_NTS);  // so, I need to change this data only!

// Allocate a statement handle.
var hStmt = new SqlHandle();

sqlAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hConn, hStmt);

// Prepare a statement.
sqlPrepare(hStmt, "select * from Vendors", SQL_NTS);   // I need to print the output of this SQL!!

// Execute and fetch some data.
sqlExecute(hStmt);

sqlFetch(hStmt);


// Free statement handle.
sqlFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);

// Disconnect.
sqlDisconnect(hConn);

// Free connection handle.
sqlFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hConn);

// Free environment handle.
sqlFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv); 

}
```

thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the code to your question that demonstrates what you have tried and please also add the error message you got.

Comment: I did not know what parameters/attributes I need to change in the basic example,, in real I did not know what shall I do :( I'm not familiar with ODBC, I read this to get some idea, http://old.vk.pp.ru/docs/sybase-any/interfaces/00000034.htm but still confused. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for Juan, the pub author.
my mistake was, I'm using Windows x64, and defined my ODBC using std ODBC, did not notice, that this pub is for 32 bit, and I've to define the ODBC using:

> (YOUR WINDOW DIRECTORY)\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe

[image]

the below code worked perfectly

```dart
import 'package:odbc/odbc.dart';

void main() {
     var hEnv = new SqlHandle();
     sqlAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, null, hEnv);

     var version = new SqlPointer()..value = SQL_OV_ODBC3;
    sqlSetEnvAttr(hEnv, SQL_ATTR_ODBC_VERSION, version, 0);

    var hConn = new SqlHandle();
    sqlAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hEnv, hConn);

    sqlConnect(hConn, "<DSN>", SQL_NTS, "<USER>", SQL_NTS, "<PASS>", SQL_NTS);

    var hStmt = new SqlHandle();

    sqlAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hConn, hStmt);

    sqlPrepare(hStmt, "SELECT * FROM vendors", SQL_NTS);

    var col1 = new SqlLongBuffer();
    var flags1 = new SqlIntBuffer();
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 1, col1.ctype(), col1.address(), 0, flags1.address());

    var col2 = new SqlLongBuffer();
    var flags2 = new SqlIntBuffer();
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 2, col2.ctype(), col2.address(), 0, flags2.address());

    var col3 = new SqlStringBuffer(255);
    var flags3 = new SqlIntBuffer();
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 3, col3.ctype(), col3.address(), col3.length(), flags3.address());

    var col4 = new SqlStringBuffer(255);
    var flags4 = new SqlIntBuffer();
    sqlBindCol(hStmt, 4, col4.ctype(), col4.address(), col4.length(), flags4.address());

    sqlExecute(hStmt);

    while (sqlFetch(hStmt) != SQL_NO_DATA_FOUND) {
          print("${col1.peek()} ${col2.peek()} ${col3.peek()} ${col4.peek()} ");
     }

   sqlFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_STMT, hStmt);

   sqlDisconnect(hConn);

   sqlFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, hConn);

   sqlFreeHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, hEnv);
}
```

Table created:

```dart
      CREATE TABLE vendors (
             vendor_id NUMBER,
             vCode NUMBER,
             vName VARCHAR(255),
             vEmail VARCHAR(255),
             PRIMARY KEY (vendor_id));
```

Input data:

```dart
 INSERT INTO vendors VALUES(1, 111, 'One', 'one@vendors.com')
 INSERT INTO vendors VALUES(2, 222, 'Two', 'two@vendors.com');
 INSERT INTO vendors VALUES(3, 33, 'Three', 'three@vendors.com');
```

Console output:

```dart
     Observatory listening on http://127.0.0.1:49433
 1 111 One one@vendors.com 
 2 222 Two two@vendors.com 
 3 33 Three three@vendors.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This code line of the example code from the ODBC package README shows that you have to pass cutom
`<YOUR DSN>`, `<YOUR USER ID>`, `<YOUR PASSWORD>`

```dart
sqlConnect(hConn, "<YOUR DSN>", SQL_NTS, "<YOUR USER ID>", SQL_NTS, "<YOUR PASSWORD>", SQL_NTS);
```

The `<YOUR DSN>` of your screenshot is `XE`. I don't know your user name and password :-P

Comment: Only these data required to be changed!! What about the SQL.. If I want to use print() to check print the output of the SELECT statement.. What shall I do!!

Comment: I don't know what you expect, you didn't even provide any information about how your database/tables/data look like and what SQL statement you want to have executed. If you want to execute the SQL in the example you don't have to change it. Your database needs to have the tables and fields referenced in the SQL statement.

Comment: I updated my question with some codes, as per my understanding so far, after your comments..